# Loop simplify python

Tags: python

What do I try to do? Extract every 10 records of a given list and append it to another list. The main list can have 100.000 records or even more, I want to get 10 and 10 records then again more 10, etc.
how do I use a loop here to eliminate the need of `A1..A10`? Also a more efficient replacement way for `index+10`?

```
TEST = [
    'AA',
    'BB',
    'CC',
    'DD',
    'EE',
    'FF',
    'GG',
    'HH',
    'II',
    'JJ',
'11',
'22',
'33',
'44',
'55',
'66',
'77',
'88',
'99',
'10',
]

index = 0

while index < len(TEST):
    A1  = TEST[index+0].rstrip('\n')
    A2  = TEST[index+1].rstrip('\n')
    A3  = TEST[index+2].rstrip('\n')
    A4  = TEST[index+3].rstrip('\n')
    A5  = TEST[index+4].rstrip('\n')
    A6  = TEST[index+5].rstrip('\n')
    A7  = TEST[index+6].rstrip('\n')
    A8  = TEST[index+7].rstrip('\n')
    A9  = TEST[index+8].rstrip('\n')
    A10 = TEST[index+9].rstrip('\n')

    index = index+10

    accs_lst=[]
    accs_lst.append(A1)
    accs_lst.append(A2)
    accs_lst.append(A3)
    accs_lst.append(A4)
    accs_lst.append(A5)
    accs_lst.append(A6)
    accs_lst.append(A7)
    accs_lst.append(A8)
    accs_lst.append(A9)
    accs_lst.append(A10)
    

for i in accs_lst:
  print(i)
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Use a `for` loop instead of `while`?

Comment: `accs_lst = [x.rstrip('\n') for x in TEST]`, I believe will replace that whole monstrosity.

Comment: For the record, looping 10 at a time really isn't any more efficient than looping one at a time, which is the intention of your loop to begin with.

Comment: What @JNevill says.  The type of code you have here (an "unrolled loop") is a technique sometimes used to micro-optimise assembly language in particular circumstances when it helps to squeeze a little bit more performance out of the code.  It's rare for it to be useful in Python.

Comment: idk, looking at the code, it seems that `for x in TEST: print(x)` would suffice (can add that `rstrip` if necessary but given the contents of `TEST` that doesn't seem necessary either)

Comment: @Matiiss That would likely do it. There is nothing to `rstrip()` and ultimately the list is just printed. I assume there is just the minimal reproducible sample code and the real `TEST` input list has some ugly data that needs cleaning?

Comment: Did you notice that *accs_lst* only contains the last 10 items from the *TEST* list?

Comment: Just a doubt: why are `while` loops even used in cases where the `for` loop can achieve the same thing? I guess [`for` loops are faster than `while` loops in Python](https://www.pythonpool.com/for-vs-while-loop-python/#:~:text=On%20basis%20of,than%20for%20loop.).

Comment: @Stuart Why so ?

Comment: @IrinelIovan because *accs_lst=[]* - i.e., the list is reset every iteration of the while loop

Comment: Also, the code in the original question will only work if `len(TEST)` is an exact multiple of 10.

Comment: If for some reason you wanted to retrieve items from a source 10 at a time (maybe it's some slow resource which is more efficient that way), one technique is a generator that pulls 10 items at a time, then yields them one by one.  When processing the items, you can just iterate over that generator with a normal `for` loop, without the code needing to be aware that under the hood the generator happens to batch up its work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a loop inside your loop, and use `extend` to append each item from the inner loop to your list without having to actually call `append` ten times.  You also probably want to move the `accs_lst = []`, as noted:

```
accs_lst=[]  # set this outside the loop so it doesn't get reset each time
for index in range(0, len(TEST), 10):
    accs_lst.extend(a.rstrip('\n') for a in TEST[index:index+10])

for i in accs_lst:
    print(i)
```

Note that given your sample input the `rstrip` doesn't do anything, and given that you're just appending all the items to `accs_lst` anyway there's no reason to do it in chunks of ten.

Assuming you did need to apply `rstrip` to all the `TEST` elements to produce `accs_lst`, you could get rid of the chunk-by-ten thing and accomplish it more simply in a single line:

```
accs_lst = [a.rstrip('\n') for a in TEST]
```

If the idea is to do something with each distinct batch of ten items inside the loop, here's an example that makes it easier to see how that would work:

```
for index in range(0, len(TEST), 10):
    accs_lst = [a + "!" for a in TEST[index:index+10]]
    print(*accs_lst)
```

which for your sample TEST input produces:

```
AA! BB! CC! DD! EE! FF! GG! HH! II! JJ!
11! 22! 33! 44! 55! 66! 77! 88! 99! 10!
```

Comment: The fun is that whole code could be replaced with `print(*TEST, sep="\n")`

Comment: I don't need rstrip.  It was my mistake.. i edited question with more info above.

Comment: Added another example to my answer that might actually be closer to the thing you're trying to do -- based on your updated question it sounds like you might want to do something with `accs_lst` *inside* the loop rather than outside of it.

Comment: If your example is actually reading from an iterator (which you can't slice the same way you can slice a list) then you might do something like `accs_lst = [next(i) for _ in range(10)]` to pull 10 items from the iterator and stick them in `accs_lst`.